# Website cache on google looks broken

Tags: seo

My website's google cache copy looks broken.

Below is link to cache.

`http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://paintcollar.com`

Can this affect the SERPs and crawling by google?

What can I do to rectify it?

PS. Few pages are being cached properly though.Below is URL to one such page.
`http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://paintcollar.com/aneel`

Comment: The css you have referenced returns the home page, no css styles. I see you have a new css file on the current version and that does seem to return css. Hopefully on next crawl, it should resolve itself.

Comment: As previously explained, individual website reviews and troubleshooting are considered off-topic for this site since that's unlikely to help others in the futures (e.g.,. problems get resolved, sites change, become unavailable, etc...). Questions here need to be helpful to others since this is a reference site. In the future, you'll need to use screenshots and/or describe the issue completely in your post, using generic URLs (not URLs to your site). Also, comments should be added below posts, not inside of them.

Answer (score 3):

When Google fetches any page, the first thing it does is store the code. The reason for this is simple. Google needs to process your web page in different ways at different times and it is far better to reference your page from it's index than to fetch it each and every time.

This is where the cache comes from.

If you see that the cache does not look as you expect, that is always a code issue. In your case, what I see wrong is extremely easy to fix.

Your CSS code is relative and not absolute. This means that when someone requests the cache page, the reference to the CSS files causes the browser to fetch the CSS files from a location where they are not.

> **This is NOT a problem!!**

Here is your code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/583bff26.vendor.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/f8c12610.main.css"/>
```

I recommend making this code absolute.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/583bff26.vendor.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/f8c12610.main.css"/>
```

You can always use the full reference.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://paintcollar.com/styles/583bff26.vendor.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://paintcollar.com/styles/f8c12610.main.css"/>
```

For the record, many sites are relative `css/style.css` as apposed to absolute, however, the most common absolute reference is `/css/style.css`

Comment: Don't use http: in links. Just href="//your site.Dom/path to.CSS"  Then page will still work If you go SSL some day. Might as well start the habit now, even if you don't plan for SSL.

Comment: @Lenne You know... I almost made the reference the way you suggested, I just did not want to be confusing. Nice suggestion! Cheers!!

Comment: Protocol-relative URLs (i.e. "//paintcollar.com" rather than "http://paintcollar.com") are no longer considered a good practice: https://www.jeremywagner.me/blog/stop-using-the-protocol-relative-url/